# Android - Create a dialog which uses existing actionbar

Tags: android, dialog

I'm looking to create a dialog which allows me to interface the existing action bar from the parent activity. i.e I have a menu button so if the dialog is open I can still open the menu.

Here is how I create the window:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.alpha = 1.0f;
    params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
    this.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);

    // This sets the window size, while working around the IllegalStateException thrown by ActionBarView
    this.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    this.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    init(CompareViewActivity.this);
    setContentView(currentView);


}
```

Comment: What is your problem/question?

Comment: How can i open the menu while the dialog is open?

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to have access to a the ActionBar while a Dialog is in use